# Charging option using jquery/javascript. 'Math' logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement an advertising system that will charge a user according to their preference. By default, if the user did not select any options, their ads will be shown on all devices. I will only charge them if they choose specific devices.

If the user selects mobile, it will show 'ios', 'android' and 'windows phone' check boxes. Each option is USD 1. So, if the user selects mobile and iOS, it will be charged USD 2 and so on. If the user selects all options, it will be USD0.00 because since by default, their ads will be shown on all devices and I'm not charging a cent.

Also, the last condition would be : If I clicked on 'Mobile' and it shows 'ios', 'Android' and 'Windows Phone', if I select either one of it, it suppose to not add another USD1. 
For example: 'Mobile' would be USD1, if I choose 'ios', it would be also USD1. But if I choose 'ios' and 'Android', it would be USD2.

I've code it myself and it doesn't seems to work like the way I want to, and need your help.

Here's the partially working code that I made:

HTML

```
<label class="checkbox inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="device" value="0.01" id="checkbox_mobile" onclick='add(1, this);'/> Mobile
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline">
    <input type="checkbox" class="device" value="0.01" onclick='add(1, this);'/> PC
</label>
<br>
<label class="checkbox inline mobile">
    <input type="checkbox" class="os" id="mobile1" value="0.01" onclick='add2(1, this);'/> iOS
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline mobile">
    <input type="checkbox" class="os" id="mobile2" value="0.01" onclick='add2(1, this);'/> Android
</label>
<label class="checkbox inline mobile">
    <input type="checkbox" class="os" id="mobile3" value="0.01" onclick='add2(1, this);'/> Windows Phone
</label>
    <br></br>
<input style="display:none;" id="pool" name="pool" value="0">
<input style="display:none;" id="pool2" name="pool2" value="0">
USD<input id="total" name="total" value="0">
```

Jquery

```
 $('.mobile').hide();

$('#checkbox_mobile').change(function(){
    $('.mobile').toggle();
});

function add(value, this_chk_bx) {
    if (document.getElementById("checkbox_mobile").checked == false){
        document.getElementById("pool2").value = 0;
        $('#mobile1').attr('checked', false);
        $('#mobile2').attr('checked', false);
        $('#mobile3').attr('checked', false);
    }

    if ($('input[class="device"]:checked').length == 2) {
        value = document.getElementById("pool").value * 1 + value;
        document.getElementById("pool").value = value;
        document.getElementById("total").value = 0;
    } else {
        if (this_chk_bx.checked == true) {
            // Add if its checked
            value = document.getElementById("pool").value * 1 + value;
            document.getElementById("pool").value = value;
            document.getElementById("total").value = document.getElementById("pool").value*1+document.getElementById("pool2").value*1;
        } else {
            // Subtract if its unchecked
            value = document.getElementById("pool").value * 1 - value;
            document.getElementById("pool").value = value;
            document.getElementById("total").value = document.getElementById("pool").value*1+document.getElementById("pool2").value*1;
        }
    }
};

function add2(value, this_chk_bx) {
    if ($('input[class="os"]:checked').length == 3) {
        value = document.getElementById("pool2").value * 1 + value;
        document.getElementById("pool2").value = value;
    } else {
        if (this_chk_bx.checked == true) {
            // Add if its checked
            value = document.getElementById("pool2").value * 1 + value;
            document.getElementById("pool2").value = value;
            document.getElementById("total").value = document.getElementById("pool").value*1+document.getElementById("pool2").value*1;
        } else {
            // Subtract if its unchecked
            value = document.getElementById("pool2").value * 1 - value;
            document.getElementById("pool2").value = value;
            document.getElementById("total").value = document.getElementById("pool").value*1+document.getElementById("pool2").value*1;
        }
    }
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hh739j7t/1/

It doesn't reset USD to 0 if all options are ticked.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to select all checkboxes by default?

Comment: Why the inconsistent use of jQuery?

Comment: @blex, if all were checked, the user will have to uncheck most of it if he/she just need one option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace your onclick function with this:

```
function computeTotal() {
    // get all mobile
    var mobileList = document.getElementsByName("mobile"),
        chkCount = 0,
        i = 0,
        len = mobileList.length,
        totalMobile = 0;
    for (; i < len; i ++) {
        if (mobileList[i].checked) {
            chkCount += 1;
        }
    }
    totalMobile = chkCount;

    // get all pc
    var pcList = document.getElementsByName("pc"),
        totalPC = 0;
    // reset value of these variables
    chkCount = 0;
    i = 0;
    len = pcList.length;
    for (; i < len; i ++) {
        if (pcList[i].checked) {
            chkCount += 1;
        }
    }
    totalPC = chkCount;


    // compute total
    var total = 0;
    if (totalMobile == mobileList.length && totalPC == pcList.length) {
        // total is zero since all device is selected
    } else if (totalMobile == mobileList.length && totalPC != pcList.length) {
        total = totalPC;
    } else {
        total = totalMobile + totalPC;
    }

    // display
    document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

and also, add a **name** attribute to your device's checkbox. for pc device, the **name** value is **pc** and **mobile** for mobile devices.

Comment: I've modified a little. However, if mobile and pc are checked, the total has to be 0 too. And another condition would be, if the User clicked on mobile and ios, the total is only '1'. The first OS option that the user chose is not counted. I've update a new jsfiddle using your code. http://jsfiddle.net/aew5bmyL/